# VS2015 Character syntax colors displaying incorrectly

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Recently I started using VS.NET 2015 and imported my settings I've used in VS2010 and VS2013 without a hitch. However, something with my color scheme is odd and I can't seem to find the color setting or other setting to correct.

Essentially most of my non-alphanumeric syntax in C# like the following all show up in **black**:

`{ } ( ) , . = ;`

The picture gives an idea:

[image]

Does anyone know which IDE color setting would cause this or some other issue? Normally these characters in C# are white and that is what I was hoping to configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you think you can use [Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b)? It is directly from the Microsoft. It has access to 2700+ VS IDE color settings (switch it to `Show All Elements` mode) and there you can check all colors starting with `Text Editor →`. Modify the one which causes the problem.

Perhaps it is `Text Editor → Punctuation → Foreground`.

This way you should be quickly able to fix your color scheme.

Note: only custom color schemes can be edited, so you might need to clone existing built-in color scheme into custom one before you can enter color editor.

Comment: EUREKA!!! `Text Editor → Punctuation → Foreground` was the problem as well as `Text Editor → Operator → Foreground`. Ahhh, I can see my code :D I did also download the color theme editor. I wanted to use it's color picker as you mentioned, but I think what you were mentioning was just to clone a theme to use the tool set, but not necessarily apply. I have my own custom theme already and don't want a canned one, but assumed that was a suggestion to use the tools, correct?

Comment: Yes. My point was that (as you perhaps found by yourself) editor won't let you edit built-in themes, only custom themes. Good to see it helped.